# Add to cart button in Lightbox2?

Tags: paypal, lightbox2

I'm trying to add a PayPal "add to cart" button to my lightbox 2 gallery?? I've seen lots of trouble shooting (posted by ChrisD), however, I can't locate the actual code to get it into the lightbox. I can get it to be in my caption on the index, but the button won't go into the actual lighbox display container where I would prefer it? Any help would be greatly appreciated!! (or direct me to a link/question that answers this?)Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Payments Standard buttons aren't meant to work within a frame or an iframe or launch an iframe. They need to launch in a window outside of your lightbox.

Comment: thank you for answering.. I saw it done on [http://lancemissionart.com]([http://lancemissionart.com) and another post [http://www.dynamicdrive.com](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/forums/showthread.php?50058-Lightbox-2-with-Paypal-Integration)  had the converter to make it work with other instructions based on mission art, but I just can't get all the ducks in a row so to speak. :/  hmmmm? Any ideas based on those two links? -- sorry My first time on stack, had to edit a couple times to get links to work!

Comment: ok - still can't get the links right!... ??? lol sorry.. but the blue is the link, but doesn't work, and the grey after that goes to the instructions?? lol sorry, four edits best I can do right now!!

Comment: The buttons on that page are opening outside of the iframe. The site you linked has the PayPal form contained in this tag <a rel="lightbox[sd]" title="Mission San Diego Print 1" paypalForm